# Why does $F:P\otimes−:Mod_R\to Mod_R$ define an equivalence of categories?

Tags: category-theory, modules, homological-algebra

Let $P$ be a finitely generated projective R-module of rank 1 which is not free.
Let $F:P\otimes_R−:Mod_R\to Mod_R$ be the functor.
We have that $R$ is free and $F(R)=P\otimes_R R\simeq P$ is not free.

If $F$ did define a equivalence of category, we would prove that "**Free**" is not a categorical property.

But **why does $F$ define a equivalence of categories?** (I suppose that the fact that $P$ is projective plays an important role).

Let $p$ be the generator of $P$.
The natural transformation $\alpha_M:M\to M\otimes_R P$ defined as $\alpha_M(m)= m\otimes p$ may not define a natural isomorphism: $\alpha_M$ may not be an ismorphism for every $M$.

Comment: I think you probably want to specify that $R$ is commutative and that the tensor is $\otimes_R$ rather than just $\otimes$, otherwise you wouldn't be able to conclude $P\otimes_R R\cong P$.

Comment: Also, regarding the background question, it seems useful just to note that over a field $F$ every module is free, and the category of $F$-modules is equivalent to the category of $M_2(F)$-modules, which has non-free modules.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have edited my question in relation to tensor product. But, must $R$ be commutative? That is to say, given a non-commutative ring R and a $R$-module $M$, do not we have that $M\otimes_R R\simeq M$?

Comment: No, I guess it is still find for the result $M\otimes_R R\cong R_R$ since $R$ is a bimodule.  I just though you might be assuming without saying.

Comment: @Sampah I think the point is the opposite: this gives an example of why it isn't.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Ah I see. I happened to misread it. Thanks.

Comment: @rschwieb gives us an excellent example: There are two equivalent categories: $K$-Module (where $K$ is a field) and $M_2(K)$-Module. Let $F$  be the functor defining this equivalence from $K$-Module to $M_2(K)$-Module. Exists $M$ that is free in $K$-Module but $F(M)$ is not free in $M_2(K)$-Module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the comment by rschwieb, it is easy to see that **'free' is not a categorical property**.

In relation to my specific question about the functor $F$, I have just found a theorem by Morita that explains the reason why $F$ defines a equivalence of categories. I have found it in Rotman's book "An introduction to Homological Algebra", page 269. **All these ideas are developed in Morita Theory**.

The general idea would be the following:

We need to define another functor $G = Hom_R(P,-)$. Since $F$ and $G$ are adjoint, they define two natural transformation $FG\to 1_R$ and $1_R\to GF$.

Since $P$ is a small projective generator of $Mod_R$, we have that these natural transformation are also isomorphism.

All the details can be found in the proof:

**Theorem 5.55**. Let $R$ be a ring and let $P$ be a small projective generator of $Mod_R$. If $S = End_R(P)$, then there is an isomorphism $F : Mod_S \to Mod_R$ given by $M \to M \otimes_S P$.

Comment: (It may be a good idea to note that Morita *developed* these ideas systematically, into something we call today, well... Morita theory!)

Comment: Yes. You are right!. I have just found it out.

Comment: @AntonioHernando nice job with the self answer. This is a fairly good time to use it.